# LanguageTool on LibreOffice installing error

Tags: libreoffice

When I'm trying to install LanguageTool for LibreOffice I get: "an error ocurred writing or reading from a file".

Answer (score 2):

Install this package `openoffice.org-java-common` package. Just search for it in the software center